# Check row by row in QTableWidget to affect QCombobox

Tags: python, pyqt, maya, qtablewidget, qcombobox

I have a QTableWidget, 2 Columns in which the first column contains the name of items while the second column is populated with qcomboboxes (created using cellwidgets) which contains a list of color options (eg. "", RED, BLUE, GREEN)

For example, in the following table, items denoted with * has a variable called `color_set`, I am trying to achieve as follows:

- it will lookup the names of items in the scene
- then it will go through a function to check and see if the item
  `shirt_01` contains a variable called `color_set`
- If the variable exists, say if it is RED, it will then lookup the list of options in the combobox and display RED as the value
- If the variable does not exists, it will displays a blank field instead
- this function/values populate the table with information before the ui is launched, it is not a button clicked function etc.

  ```
  Name of items   | Color Options
    shirt_01*     |     RED
    shirt_02      | 
    pants*        |    GREEN
  ```

However, instead of getting my ui to output as above, I got the following result:

```
    Name of items   | Color Options
      shirt_01*     |     RED
      shirt_02      |     RED
      pants*        |    GREEN
```

For some reasons, the `shirt_02` seems to got 'tangled' and displayed the same result as `shirt_01`. And I think it could possibly be due to how my logic was written but I could not figure it out or because I keep tying my output result to `self.color_combobox` as my code initially checks through the first column then find the matching text in the second column.
But I keep getting error at the line - item_name has no attribute .text()

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import json

def get_all_mesh():
    all_mesh = cmds.listRelatives(cmds.ls(type = 'mesh'), parent=True)
    return all_mesh

def read_json(node_name):
    # checks if the node_name exists in the json file
    with open('/Desktop/car_colors.json') as data_file:
        data = json.load(data_file)

        items = set()
        for index, name in enumerate(data):
            # if the name is in the json, it will states the color
            if node_name in name:
                for item in (data[name]):
                    #print "{0} - {1}".format(name, item)
                    items.add(item)
    return items

def attrToPy(objAttr):
    stringAttrData = str(cmds.getAttr(objAttr))
    loadedData = cPickle.loads(stringAttrData)

    return loadedData


class testTableView(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setWindowTitle('Color Test')
        self.setModal(False)

        self.all_mesh = get_all_mesh()

        # Build the GUI
        self.init_ui()
        self.populate_data()


    def init_ui(self):
        # Table setup
        self.mesh_table = QtGui.QTableWidget()
        self.mesh_table.setRowCount(len(self.all_mesh))
        self.mesh_table.setColumnCount(3)
        self.mesh_table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Mesh Found', 'Color for Mesh'])
        self.md_insert_color_btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Apply color')

        # Layout
        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.mesh_table)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.md_insert_color_btn)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def populate_data(self):
        geo_name = self.all_mesh

        for row_index, geo_item in enumerate(geo_name):
            new_item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(geo_item)
            # Add in each and every mesh found in scene and append them into rows
            self.mesh_table.setItem(row_index, 0, new_item)

            geo_exclude_num = ''.join(i for i in geo_item if not i.isdigit())
            color_list = read_json(geo_exclude_num)

            color_list.add("")
            # Insert in the color
            self.color_combobox = QtGui.QComboBox()
            #color_list = get_color()
            self.color_combobox.addItems(list(sorted(color_list)))
            self.mesh_table.setCellWidget(row_index, 1, self.color_combobox)
            self.color_value_to_combobox()

    def color_value_to_combobox(self):
        obj_nodes = get_all_mesh()
        for node in obj_nodes:
            # This attribute is stored in the Extra Attributes
            objAttr = '%s.pyPickle'%node
            storedData = attrToPy(objAttr)

            if 'color_set' in storedData:
                color_variant = storedData['color_set']
                combo_index = self.color_combobox.findText(color_variant, QtCore.Qt.MatchFixedString)
                self.color_combobox.setCurrentIndex(0 if combo_index < 0 else combo_index)


# To opent the dialog window
dialog = testTableView()
dialog.show()
```

Is there anyway in which I can make my ui to check for the list of item in scene, tallies which name and combobox it should go (in terms of which rows/columns)? Otherwise what other ways can i approach?

EDIT: This is the attachment that I did it quick - [Link](https://www.mediafire.com/?fy67i4105j6z1tp)
If you run the UI, you will notice that pCube1 has the color "red" while pCube2 is "blue", however both the comboboxes will turn up as blue instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the problem was in `color_value_to_combobox`. Instead of setting the combobox for ALL objects, you need to specify what object and combobox the function needs to work on. The major flaw was that you were using `self.color_combobox` to set with every time, so every object would keep setting the same combobox! It needs to be more generic.

Anyways, I just had to change the end of `populate_data` and `color_value_to_combobox`. Now `cube1` shows `red`, and `cube2` shows `blue`.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import json
import cPickle

def get_all_mesh():
    all_mesh = cmds.listRelatives(cmds.ls(type = 'mesh'), parent=True)
    return all_mesh

def read_json(node_name):
    # checks if the node_name exists in the json file
    with open('/Desktop/car_colors.json') as data_file:
        data = json.load(data_file)

        items = set()
        for index, name in enumerate(data):
            # if the name is in the json, it will states the color
            if node_name in name:
                for item in (data[name]):
                    #print "{0} - {1}".format(name, item)
                    items.add(item)
    return items

def attrToPy(objAttr):
    stringAttrData = str(cmds.getAttr(objAttr))
    loadedData = cPickle.loads(stringAttrData)

    return loadedData


class testTableView(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setWindowTitle('Color Test')
        #self.setModal(False)

        self.all_mesh = get_all_mesh()

        # Build the GUI
        self.init_ui()
        self.populate_data()


    def init_ui(self):
        # Table setup
        self.mesh_table = QtGui.QTableWidget()
        self.mesh_table.setRowCount(len(self.all_mesh))
        self.mesh_table.setColumnCount(3)
        self.mesh_table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Mesh Found', 'Color for Mesh'])
        self.md_insert_color_btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Apply color')

        # Layout
        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.mesh_table)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.md_insert_color_btn)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def populate_data(self):
        geo_name = self.all_mesh

        for row_index, geo_item in enumerate(geo_name):
            new_item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(geo_item)
            # Add in each and every mesh found in scene and append them into rows
            self.mesh_table.setItem(row_index, 0, new_item)

            geo_exclude_num = ''.join(i for i in geo_item if not i.isdigit())
            color_list = read_json(geo_exclude_num)

            color_list.add("")
            # Insert in the color
            color_combobox = QtGui.QComboBox()
            #color_list = get_color()
            color_combobox.addItems(list(sorted(color_list)))
            self.mesh_table.setCellWidget(row_index, 1, color_combobox)

            self.color_value_to_combobox(geo_item, color_combobox) # Pass the object and combobox you want to set

    # This use to work on all mesh objects, but only edits a single combobox. This is wrong!
    def color_value_to_combobox(self, node, combobox):
        # This attribute is stored in the Extra Attributes
        objAttr = '%s.pyPickle'%node
        storedData = attrToPy(objAttr)

        if 'color_set' in storedData:
            color_variant = storedData['color_set']
            combo_index = combobox.findText(color_variant, QtCore.Qt.MatchFixedString)
            combobox.setCurrentIndex(0 if combo_index < 0 else combo_index) # Needs to work on the proper combobox!


# To opent the dialog window
dialog = testTableView()
dialog.show()
```

Comment: Actually, using `self.color_combobox` makes no difference at all, because it's constantly reset. The real flaw is the extra for-loop in `color_value_to_combobox`. The simplest fix is to comment out the top three lines of `color_value_to_combobox`, and change `node` to `geo_item`. In other words, put it all in one for-loop, like I did in my answer ;-)

Comment: He was looping through all objects in `color_value_to_combobox` and setting the value to the same combobox, `self.color_combobox`. In fact, before he was looping through all objects in both `populate_data` and `color_value_to_combobox` which made no sense. We essentially did the same answer; you just merged the two functions, which is fine, while I just made the function need parameters to specify the object and combobox. I did test this example with his supplied files, and it does work.

Comment: @GreenCell your code works to my case, thank you. I am getting the inkling that this is something to do with the `self.color_combobox` that I have created as I have been calling the same thing for use in my code. Just not sure how to get it resolved.

Comment: @ekhumoro I also did use some of the code in some of my code that you did and merge it together with the portion that GreenCell did. Thanks guys!

Comment: Just wondering if you could tell me why does storing the comboboxes in a list is a 'better' idea? And how much difference can it be between the list method and this answer, seeing that both gives the same result? Also, should the TS be using the list method, I suppose he will need to add this line `for i in self.combo_ls[-1:]` in the `color_value_to_combobox` function?

Comment: I may have jump the gun on saying to put it in a list because there's a table that you can reference the combobox's with `self.mesh_table.cellwidget`. But if there wasn't a table I would append them to a list just so there's a way to reference them later!

Comment: @yan, why is there a [-1:] for your list? Shouldn't it be just `for I in self.combo_ls`? Correct me if I am wrong on this.

Comment: @GreenCell suppose if I create a `self.combo_list = []`, do you mean to say that to add in the combo boxes, it will be `self.combo_list.append(self.mesh_table.cellWidget)` instead of `self.combo_list.append(self.color_combobox)`?

Comment: @dissidia What I meant in my last comment is that I don't think you need a list after all, because let's say you needed to get the combobox from the 2nd row, the table already gives you that functionality to fetch it with `self.mesh_table.cellWidget(1, 1)`. I only mentioned the list before because usually when making dynamic guis you need to keep track of your sub-widgets somehow in an easy way. Luckily the table already does this!

Comment: @GreenCell I see, well earlier I tried creating a list and appending the comboboxes (to test it out), and I am getting back the same issue. Unless I use the `[-1:]` as mentioned by Yan, only then each item is populating the correct color in the comboboxes

Comment: Apparently my list got printed like 3 times, first print only contains the 1 combobox, the second contains 2 comboboxes, while the third contains all 3 comboboxes. For some reasons, when I print my list in the `populate_table_data`, my list is printing correctly, but when I tried calling it in the `color_value_to_combobox`, it is not printing correctly

Comment: Is there some reason you insist on doing this? ekhumoro or my solution does what you want.

Answer (score 2):

If the color variable doesn't exist, your code needs to explicitly set the color combo to a blank item:

```
def populate_data(self):
    geo_name = self.all_mesh

    for row_index, geo_item in enumerate(geo_name):
        new_item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(geo_item)
        # Add in each and every mesh found in scene and append them into rows
        self.mesh_table.setItem(row_index, 0, new_item)

        geo_exclude_num = ''.join(i for i in geo_item if not i.isdigit())
        color_list = read_json(geo_exclude_num)

        color_list.add("")
        # Insert in the color
        color_combobox = QtGui.QComboBox()
        #color_list = get_color()
        color_combobox.addItems(list(sorted(color_list)))
        self.mesh_table.setCellWidget(row_index, 1, color_combobox)

        # This attribute is stored in the Extra Attributes
        objAttr = '%s.pyPickle' % geo_item
        storedData = attrToPy(objAttr)

        if 'color_set' in storedData:
            color_variant = storedData['color_set']
        else:
            color_variant = ''

        combo_index = color_combobox.findText(color_variant, QtCore.Qt.MatchFixedString)
        color_combobox.setCurrentIndex(0 if combo_index < 0 else combo_index)
```

(NB: for this to work, you obviously must make sure the first entry in the combo-boxes is a blank item).

Comment: I am getting error `# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' # ` at the line `item_name = str(item_col.text())`, using `currentText` also gives me the same error... Any ideas?

Comment: @dissidia. Those lines come *before* the section of code my answer refers to. Are you claiming that the changes that I suggested are somehow *causing* those errors?

Comment: I tried replacing your code over mine, at the for loop but I am getting error.. But even so, when I omit out the lines with `item_name`, I am still getting the same output where `shirt_02` is RED

Comment: @dissidia. In that case, the code you are actually running is not the same as what is in your question. There is nothing in the code I posted that would cause that error. Please edit your question and show the **full** code that you are actually running.

Comment: @dissidia. PS: have you made sure that the combo-boxes all have a blank entry as item zero?

Comment: There were some codes that I have used which I cannot show here.. I will try and see if I can create and upload a scene/files here

Comment: @dissidia. I have edited your question and added the actual code. Please do not link to off-site resources like mediafire. Looking at your code, it seems you did not copy my solution properly, so I have updated my answer to show how to do it. However, I cannot actually test anything, because your code requires maya.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126044/discussion-between-dissidia-and-ekhumoro).

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the code you posted, it doesn't show the loop over the rows to put the combo boxes in each cell,  but I will assume there is one otherwise it wouldn't work at all.

What you should do is one of two things:
- if you have a separate loop to create your combo boxes then in that loop don't create a combo box if the item does not have colors; then in the second loop you check if the cell has a combo box and only if it does do you configure it. 
- Second option is to move the first loop into the rows loop, ie you as loop through each row you determine if the item has colors, and only if it does,  do you create the combo box and configure it; if no colors, just leave that sell empty.